# Await keyword is not properly halting until the promise is fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I am trying to manipulate this variable within an async function and i am aware that the variable is being returned before the data.map function i will show below is complete but i am curious why? I have the await keyword in front in attempt to pause the code until the .map function is complete and then it should return the count from the .map function, but it is not, i am curious what i am doing wrong and if there is a better way to do it? Thank you!

Code:

```
const alertFetch = async () => {
      //set a count at the beginning of the endpoint
      var counter = 0;
      await data["option_activity"].map(async (item) => {
        var reply = await GET_ASYNC("alert_" + item.id);
        if (reply) {
          //If they are a repeat return nothing
          // console.log('No New Alert Detected')
        } else {
          //If they arent a repeat store the alert
          // console.log("New alert detected")
          const saveResult = await SET_ASYNC(
            "alert_" + item.id,
            JSON.stringify(item),
            "EX",
            604800
          );

          //Push it to array list in redis
          await client.get("alert_" + item.id, function (err, reply) {
            client.rpush("alerts", reply);
          });

          //Increment counter to represent how many new alers
          counter = counter + 1;
        }
      });
      console.log(counter);
      return counter;
    };
```

Comment: `map()` doest not return a promise.

Comment: You most likely need to await on the `Promise.all(thing.map(...))`

Comment: As it stands, your async function only returns the counter that is right at the bottom of your function, not the one inside Map. Map does not wait for code that assumingly it is placed in it to await for something. It is simply not async-aware...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `data['option_activity'].map` is not a promise.

see this example:

```js
let sample_arr= Array.from({ length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1));

let f= async(arr)=>{
  await Promise.all(arr.map(async item=>console.log(
    await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(()=>r(item),2000)))
  ));
  console.log('after all promises concurrent fulfilled.');
}

f(sample_arr);
```